# Unexplained memory usage in iPad iBooks?

Tags: ipad, books, storage

I have a 16GB Apple iPad 3(with Retina Display). Today, while checking up my available memory, I saw the iPad had about only 1GB left. After deleting major unused apps, I found out that **iBooks** was using up 1.4GB of storage. I found it to be extremely weird, since iBooks isn't supposed to be consuming so much of space, unless you cram thousands of ebooks in there.

I have only 4 PDFs and 4 books(purchased from the App Store). Each of these books have about a few hundred (max ~600-700) pages. So, I'm not sure how is the 1.4GB being used up by iBooks.

I'd really like to free up the space iBooks seems to be using. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A few PDF files of 500 pages with high quality graphics could easily fill up that amount of space. Check how large the PDF files are (easiest way is via iTunes under application data).

Answer (score 0):

iBooks with multi-media content, graphic novels, or comic books, can take up several orders of magnitude more memory than novels which are 99% text with a map or cover photo as their only images. Most of my books are less than 2MB. But I have a couple of books, all from the iBooks store, that are more than 100MB. PDF files can also get quite large, since layout accuracy seems to be the most important attribute.

You can check the size of your books by looking at the size of the files in the iBooks storage area:

`~/Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/Data/Documents/iBooks/Books`

Your books may also be stored in iTunes:

`~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Books`

Answer (score 0):

If you delve into your `Books` folder on-device (using an application such as iMazing), you might also find a `something.ibooks.ext` folder, which appears to be some sort of cache for images/video you had in a book already, and may be the culprit in terms of storage (use that application to make sure).  As near as I can tell, you can delete this folder with no ill effect (but I make no guarantees).